# How do I center and scale vertical harpoons?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, symbols, vertical-alignment

I need to create something very much like this:

[image]

However, I'm having trouble scaling the vertical harpoons to make them look right with the rates on either side. For the horizontal harpoons I'm using `\xleftrightharpoons`. 
Also, I need to fix it all so the `+`, the harpoons, and the `\cdot` are all aligned vertically.

What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}   
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Ras^{GDP}&+SOS & Ras^{free}&+SOS & Ras^{GTP}&+SOS
\\ 
k_{p3}&\downupharpoons{k_{m3}} &  k_{p2}&\downupharpoons{k_{m2}} &  k_{p7}&\downupharpoons{k_{m7}}
\\
Ras^{GDP}&\cdot{SOS} &\xleftrightharpoons[k_{m4}]{k_{p4}} Ras^{free}&\cdot{SOS} &\xrightleftharpoons[k_{m4}]{k_{p4}} Ras^{GTP}&\cdot{SOS}
\end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

I'd like the rates next to the vertical harpoons to look smaller and the vertical harpoons to be longer.

Also, I'm not sure why I have that huge gap left of the horizontal harpoons but I'd obviously like to center that out.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Also, in this case it really depends on how you are creating the diagram as the solutions may be different.

Comment: I think you should consider using a package such as [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) for this.

Answer (score 3):

To typeset this kind of reaction (I think this is a reaction, but I don't really have a clue what this is), you can use the [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,siunitx}
\setcompoundsep{4em}
\setarrowlabelsep{5pt}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
 R \+{0pt,0pt,0pt} GTP
 \arrow{<=>[*{0}$\scriptstyle k_{+1}$][*{0}$\scriptstyle k_{-1}$]}[-90]
 \chemfig{R\cdot GTP}
 \arrow(rgtp--){<=>[$\scriptstyle k_{+2}$][$\scriptstyle k_{-2}$]}
 \chemfig{R\cdot GDP\cdot\ P_{i}}
 \arrow{<=>[$\scriptstyle k_{+3}$][$\scriptstyle k_{-3}$]}
 \chemfig{R\cdot GDP} \+{0pt,0pt,0pt} \chemfig{P_{i}}
 \arrow{<=>[*{0}$\scriptstyle k_{-1}$][*{0}$\scriptstyle k_{+1}$]}[90] R \+{0pt,0pt,0pt} GDP
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using stacks.  I couldn't figure out an extensible harpoon (since you didn't mention a package), so I just used a scaled harpoon. EDITED to tuck the over/under harpoon labels more closely.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}%
\Shortstack[l]{%
\kern 1ex R $+$ GTP \\
$\scriptstyle k_{+1}\scalebox{2}{\rotatebox{90}{$\mkern-7mu\leftrightharpoons$}}%
  k_{-1}$\rule[-2ex]{0ex}{2ex}\\
\kern 1.5ex R $\cdot$ GTP}
\raisebox{-2pt}{\stackon[1pt]{%
  \stackunder[1pt]{\scalebox{2}{$\leftrightharpoons$}}{$\scriptstyle k_{-2}$}%
}{%
{$\scriptstyle k_{+2}$}
}}
R $\cdot$ GTP $\cdot$ P$_\mathrm{i}$
%
\raisebox{-2pt}{\stackon[1pt]{%
  \stackunder[1pt]{\scalebox{2}{$\leftrightharpoons$}}{$\scriptstyle k_{-3}$}%
}{%
{$\scriptstyle k_{+3}$}
}}
%
\Shortstack[l]{%
\kern 1ex R $+$ GTP \\
$\scriptstyle k_{+4}\scalebox{2}{\rotatebox{90}{$\mkern-7mu\leftrightharpoons$}}%
  k_{-4}$\rule[-2ex]{0ex}{2ex}\\
\kern 1.5ex R $\cdot$ GTP $+$ P$_\mathrm{i}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks really great! I'm actually using slightly different molecules, but I'm pretty sure I can change this around while keeping the sizes and alignments constant. Sorry I didn't post those the first time. Thank a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative via `tikz_cd`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=huge]
Ras^{GDP}+SOS          \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup,xshift=1ex]{d}{k_{p3}} 
& Ras^{free} + SOS     \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup,xshift=1ex]{d}{k_{p2}} 
& Ras^{GTP}+SOS        \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup,xshift=1ex]{d}{k_{p7}} \\
Ras^{GDP}\cdot SOS     \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup]{u}{k_{p3}} 
                       \arrow[thick,rightharpoonup,yshift=1ex]{r}{k_{p4}}
&  Ras^{free}\cdot SOS \arrow[thick,rightharpoonup,yshift=1ex]{r}{k_{p4}} 
                       \arrow[thick,rightharpoonup]{l}{k_{m4}} 
                       \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup]{u}{k_{m2}} %
& Ras^{GTP}\cdot SOS   \arrow[thick,rightharpoonup]{l}{k_{m4}}
                       \arrow[thick,leftharpoonup]{u}{k_{m7}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```